# NestJS Permissions Guard - the most efficient way

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, nestjs

Currently, I'm working on NestJS API. I'd like to prepare Permissions Guard and I have a problem with this. Users can have only one role, one role can have a lot of permissions. Permissions for roles are set on the Admin panel, so role permissions can be often changed. I cannot understand how can I deal with permissions in PermissionGuard. I know that I can check the current state of them in the database, but I think it's not the best way to do that because the database will be queried too often.

What should I do? Any idea?

Comment: Deeper permissions like that need to be handled somewhere in your business logic, or by using some third party authorisation service. In the documentation for nest.js, you can see that they also mentioned that you need to create authorisation mechanism yourself depending on your application needs. 
Check out this link: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authorization

Comment: You could cache each user's permissions (in redis for example) and then invalidate/update the cache whenever the admin updates a user's permission.

Answer (score -1):

Works nice. It's a JwtAuthGuard improvement and checking one permission.

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Type, mixin } from '@nestjs/common';

import { EPermission } from '../path-with-your-enum-values';
import { JWTRequestPayload } from '../request-payload-type';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './jwt-auth.guard';

export const PermissionGuard = (permission: EPermission): Type<CanActivate> => {
    class PermissionGuardMixin extends JwtAuthGuard {
        async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
            await super.canActivate(context);

            const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<JWTRequestPayload>();
            const user = request.user;

            if (!user || !user.permissions) {
                return false;
            }

            return user.permissions.includes(permission);
        }
    }

    return mixin(PermissionGuardMixin);
};
```

And with controller:

```
@Post(':taskId/moderate')
@UseGuards(PermissionGuard(EPermission.MODERATE))
public async moderate(@Param('taskId') taskId: string): Promise<any> {
    // ...
}
```